# How to group text in messages?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, lodash, javascript-objects

Good day!
I have a chat and сhat has arrays of messages.

```
[{"id":4,
"user_id":1,
"messageable_id":3,
"messageable_type":"conversation",
"text":"Text 1",
"action":null,
"target_id":null,
"created_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55",
"updated_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55",
"replies":[],
"files":[]},

{"id":5,
"user_id":1,
"messageable_id":3,
"messageable_type":"conversation",
"text":"Text 2",
"action":null,
"target_id":null,
"created_at":"2019-06-17 15:48:00",
"updated_at":"2019-06-17 15:48:00",
"replies":[],
"files":[]}]
```

I want to combine message text in one message, if the time difference is less than 60 seconds

```
[{"id":4,
"user_id":1,
"messageable_id":3,
"messageable_type":"conversation",
"grouped_text":["Text 1","Text 2"], //GROUP 
"action":null,
"target_id":null,
"created_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55",
"updated_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55",
"replies":[],
"files":[]}]
```

I try this code

```
let messages = this.$store.getters['conversation/messages'](this.conversation);
let grouped = _.groupBy(messages, message => {
    return this.$moment(message.created_at).startOf('minute');
});
```

How do i do this better? I can use lodash

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: I just try lodash function GroupBy and moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce`. If the previous message's `created_at` and current message's `created_at`'s difference is less than 1 minute (or 60,000ms), push the message to last item's `grouped_text` in accumulator. Else, push a new message to the accumulator with a `grouped_text` property

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) each message to get `text` and [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) of the properties separately

```js
const messages=[{"id":4,"user_id":1,"messageable_id":3,"messageable_type":"conversation","text":"Text 1","action":null,"target_id":null,"created_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55","updated_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55","replies":[],"files":[]},{"id":5,"user_id":1,"messageable_id":3,"messageable_type":"conversation","text":"Text 2","action":null,"target_id":null,"created_at":"2019-06-17 15:48:00","updated_at":"2019-06-17 15:48:00","replies":[],"files":[]}]

const groupDates = (date1, date2) => (new Date(date1) - new Date(date2) < 60000)

const grouped = messages.reduce((r, { text, ...rest }, i, arr) => {
  const prev = arr[i - 1];

  if (prev && groupDates(rest.created_at, prev.created_at))
    r[r.length - 1].grouped_text.push(text)
  else
    r.push({ ...rest, grouped_text: [text] })

  return r;
}, [])

console.log(grouped)
```

Note: This assumes that the messages are sorted according to the `created_at`

Answer (score 0):

The lodash's `groupBy`-function is not the right tool for this. The `groupBy`-function would put all message-objects that match the key (in your case, all messages within the same minute) into an array.

You can use the `reduce`-function. Presuming that the `messages` (the messages mentioned in your question) are ordered by date:

```js
const messages=[{"id":4,"user_id":1,"messageable_id":3,"messageable_type":"conversation","text":"Text 1","action":null,"target_id":null,"created_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55","updated_at":"2019-06-17 15:47:55","replies":[],"files":[]},{"id":5,"user_id":1,"messageable_id":3,"messageable_type":"conversation","text":"Text 2","action":null,"target_id":null,"created_at":"2019-06-17 15:48:00","updated_at":"2019-06-17 15:48:00","replies":[],"files":[]}];

const result = messages.reduce((result, message) => {
    const lastMessage = result[result.length - 1];
    if (!lastMessage || new Date(message.created_at) - new Date(lastMessage.created_at) >= 60000) {
        message.grouped_text = [message.text]
        delete message.text;
        result.push(message);
    } else {
        lastMessage.grouped_text.push(message.text);
    }
    return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```